# Get Jar/Java from INSTALL4J .exe

Tags: install4j

Hi Im new to install4j so forgive my misunderstandings, I have a x64 .exe that was built using INSTALL4J is there any way to get the java/jar out of it? does everything get compiled to PE64? This is the 7zip list of the .exe archive:

```
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2014-12-03 16:37:21 .....       173056       173056  .text
2014-12-03 16:37:21 .....        40960        40960  .rdata
2014-12-03 16:37:21 .....         9216         9216  .data
2014-12-03 16:37:21 .....         7680         7680  .pdata
                    .....         1612         1612  .rsrc\0\version.txt
                    .....          302          302  .rsrc\1033\DIALOG\101
                    .....         1188         1188  .rsrc\0\MANIFEST\1
2014-12-03 16:37:21 .....         2048         2048  .reloc
2014-12-03 16:37:21 .....         7384         7384  CERTIFICATE
2014-12-03 16:37:21 .....         3072         3072  [0]
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2014-12-03 16:37:21             246518       246518  10 files
```

There is no PK value as per [here](https://reverseengineeringtips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/unpacking-jar2exe-21-extracting-jar.html?m=1)

And another thing how do you debug such an .exe windbg can makes sense of it and a java debugger cannot see the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launchers generated by install4j do not contain the JAR files, they use JNI to create the JVM and they include external JAR files into the classpath. You can run the launcher with the `/create-i4j-log` argument to see what it is doing.

Comment: ahh ok how do you debug?

Comment: You can pass VM parameters with a `-J` prefix on the command line, i.e. `-J-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044`